# Dart native extensions - what exactly does dart-ext do on library include

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

I include the following in my native extension :-

```c
#include "qpid/client/Connection.h"
#include "qpid/client/Message.h"
#include "qpid/client/Session.h"
```

My Dart code using the native extension works, all fine and dandy, if however I include this :-

```cpp
#include "qpid/client/SubscriptionManager.h"
```

I suddenly get :-

> cannot find extension library'file:///home/steve/Development/google/dart/projects/amqp_client/lib/amqp_client.dart': error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
>   import 'dart-ext:so/amqp_extension';

So, why is this, my build system and readelf are saying there's nothing wrong with the .so file, it looks like a bug if so its a bit of show stopper for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, this was a library path problem on my development box, see issue [16140](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16140) for an explanation.